# How to embed custom thumbnail of youtube video on HTML

Tags: youtube, embed, video-thumbnails

I am trying to display thumbnail of a video on my site. I was previously trying to access the thumbnails through

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/uHi0y-pOz80/3.jpg" height="218" width="297" alt="thumbnail"/></a>
```

We had flexibility to select any of the three thumbnails that YouTube provides by mentioning `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` or `3.jpg` in the end of URL. But now with the new custom thumbnail functionality on YouTube, you can add another thumbnail which appears as your fourth option to chose for the  video. The problem is that I am not able to access that thumbnail in my website by writing `4.jpg` at the end of URL like:

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/uHi0y-pOz80/4.jpg" height="218" width="297" alt="thumbnail"/></a>
```

Does anyone know how can I access my custom thumbnail on site?

Answer (score -1):

You start counting at 0

0.jpg
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg